# Angular validator is stuck on pending

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am using Angular reactive form validation and on an the name input it remains stuck on pending after I pass the touched validation

I could not find any problem in the code itself or why the name input does this when the other inputs with validation are fine

this is in the ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$'),
        ],
      ],
      familyName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$'),
        ],
      ],
      number: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}'),
      ],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$'),
        ],
      ],
    });
  }
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label for="name">Name </label>
    <input
      formControlName="name"
      type="text"
      name="name"
      id="name"
      placeholder="Name"
    />
    <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="name?.touched && name?.invalid">
      Name is not valid
    </div>
    <label for="familyName">Family Name </label>
    <input
      formControlName="familyName"
      type="text"
      name="familyName"
      id="familyName"
      placeholder="Family Name"
    />
    <div
      class="alert-danger"
      *ngIf="familyName?.touched && familyName?.invalid"
    >
      Family Name is not valid
    </div>
    <label for="number">Phone number </label>
    <input
      formControlName="number"
      type="text"
      name="number"
      id="number"
      placeholder="Phone number"
    />
    <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="number?.touched && number?.invalid">
      Phone Number is not valid
    </div>
    <label for="email">Email </label>
    <input
      formControlName="email"
      type="text"
      name="email"
      id="email"
      placeholder="email"
    />
    <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="email?.touched && email?.invalid">
      Email is not valid
    </div>
    <label for="password">Password </label>
    <input
      formControlName="password"
      type="text"
      name="password"
      id="password"
      placeholder="password"
    />
    <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="password?.touched && password?.invalid">
      Password should have minimum 8 characters, at least 1 uppercase letter, 1
      lowercase letter and 1 number
    </div>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and in the console after writing a letter in the name input:

```
<input _ngcontent-sfk-c51="" formcontrolname="productName" type="text" productname="productName" id="productName" placeholder="productName" ng-reflect-name="productName" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-pending">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a array form your number control.

```
  number: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}'),
    ]
  ],
```

If you don't pass an array, the 3 parameter is considered an `AsyncValidtorFn`.